# What words should be used to describe "mathematically precise" music?

Tags: classical-music, counterpoint

Imagine you are working with a fugue of Bach or any other composers, which is well-written, clever, and perfect. Such music:

- Uses the minimal amount of thematic material.
- Includes very clever counterpoint, using various techniques such as stretto, inversion, etc.

What word should I use to describe such music in a formal context? I cannot say it is "studied" because this term is too broad. I cannot say it is "clever" because this is too informal. I cannot say it is "mathematical" because only people who are familiar with maths understand what I mean.

What word should I use instead of "clever"?

Comment: I'm not sure, whether the phrase *or any other composers* helps to produce good answers. E. g. Vivaldi works more with melodies, plays with rhythms so the resulting music is less formal/elaborate/whatever. I'm also sceptical, how the *minimal amount of thematic material* fits into the picture. Bruckner extensively uses his material, but earns quite some criticism from non-afficionados for doing so.

Comment: You need to define "mathematically precise music" before anyone can legitimately find words to describe it.

Comment: You may be interested in these terms: [absolute music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_music) and [economy of material](http://composersguide.com/economy-of-material/)

Comment: I don't see any good reason to close this. There is terminology to answer the question.

Answer (score 13):

For over a century people have described music by Brahms in this way; the word they often use is **academic**. Typically this word means exactly what you intend: the use of advanced, clever counterpoint and with a heavy emphasis on developed motives (and thus "minimal amount of thematic material" due to the motivic economy on display).

In other contexts, musicians will say something is **in the learned style** to describe music that uses contrapuntal techniques. But this phrase, at least in my experience, isn't specific in terms of the amount of thematic material used.

Comment: You should be aware of *connotation* as well. "academic" means roughly the same as "learned", but it  tends to be used as a criticism - often as opposed to "natural" as espoused by the Romantic movement.

Comment: There is also the connotation of academic meaning something like "according to an academic program" like Gedalge's _Treatise on Fugue._ Not the same as "in the learned style."

Comment: For non-native speakers of English it might help to know that when used in this meaning, the word "learned" has two syllables, learn-ed.

Comment: Thank you. Could you provide a reference for me to see how those words are used?

Answer (score 3):

> ...mathematical, perfect, clever...

An alternate word that you can use is ***procedural***. In fact fugue is often described as a compositional procedure rather than a form.

> ...Uses the minimal amount of thematic material.

A word that came to my mind was ***attacco***. It doesn't mean exactly minimally short fugue subject, but rather it means a short phrase treated imitatively. In a fugue an attacco could be a fragment of the subject.

Personally, I would stay away from using "mathematically precise" unless you are talking about stuff like serial music. Some fugue procedures are math-ish, but in the end it's art.

---

EDIT

Here is something that uses *attacco* to describe a type of fugue subject...

[image]

- https://books.google.com/books?id=4U1KAQAAMAAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&ppis=_e&dq=attacco%20fugue&pg=PA65#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Do you have any reference that shows me how those words are used? Something like an article the compositional style of Bach or Brahms.

Comment: Attacco, a definition in Grove's, https://books.google.com/books?id=vOQ-AAAAYAAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&ppis=_e&dq=groves%20attacco&pg=PA126#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: For _procedural_ there isn't a definition, but Mann's _Study of Fugue_ shows how it's used https://books.google.com/books?id=VXH3pnqDARoC&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&ppis=_e&lpg=PA56&dq=fugue%20mann%20procedure&pg=PA56#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Your welcome! I added another example in my answer, because it was the usage I originally thought of, but I could not find a referenced earlier. You might think about editing your original question, because it is now closed! It's a good question. If you edit it a bit, I think it will be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

One option might be **structured** (or even, for emphasis, **heavily-structured**).

That highlights the way that the thematic material is built up and organised into an overall piece.  It contrasts with more ‘free’ (and hence less-structured) music, without implying too much of a value judgement either way.

I note that that term could also be applied to Classical and Romantic pieces which developed the sonata form into its most intricate forms; though I'm not sure whether that's an argument for or against its use here :-)